# Something is wrong with my proof by induction solution

Tags: combinatorics, summation, induction, summation-method

I am trying to prove a formula by induction but I cant get it right. Something is wrong somewhere and I dont know where. Any help will be greatly appreciated.

We want to use induction to prove that:
$$\sum_{k=0}^n {n \choose k} = 2^n$$
Base Case 1: When n = 0
$$ {0 \choose 0} = 2^0 $$
Base Case 2: When n = 1
$${1 \choose 0} + { 1 \choose 1} = 2 ^ 1$$
Lets assume that the equation is true for $p < n$ where p$ >= 1$
Then the equation is true for $p - 1$
$$\sum_{k=0}^{p-1}{p-1 \choose k} = 2^{p-1}$$
$${p-1 \choose 0} + \sum_{k=1}^{p-1}{p-1 \choose k} = 2^{p-1}$$
$$\sum_{k=1}^{p-1}{p-1 \choose k} = 2^{p-1} - 1$$
Also
$$\sum_{{k - 1=0}}^{p-1}{p-1 \choose k-1} = 2^{p-1}$$
$$\sum_{k = 1}^{p-1}{p-1 \choose k-1} = 2^{p-1}$$
When we add these two equations we get:
$$\sum_{k=1}^{p-1}{p-1 \choose k} + \sum_{k = 1}^{p-1}{p-1 \choose k-1} = 2^{p-1} - 1 + 2^{p-1}$$
$$\sum_{k=1}^{p-1}{p-1 \choose k} + \sum_{k = 1}^{p-1}{p-1 \choose k-1} = 2^p - 1$$
$$\sum_{k=1}^{p-1}{({p-1 \choose k} + {p-1 \choose k-1})} = 2^p - 1$$
$$\sum_{k=1}^{p-1}{p \choose k} = 2^p - 1$$
This is where I get stuck. I can't convert it to
$$\sum_{k=0}^{p}{p \choose k} = 2^p $$

Comment: When you write $\sum_{{(k - 1)=0}}^{p-1}{p-1 \choose k-1} = 2^{p-1}$, it is $k-1=\mu$ that varies from $0$ to $p-1$. So $k$ varies from $1$ to $\color{red}p$, so your next equation is wrong.

Comment: @ShubhamJohri I thought from k-1=0, you get k = 1. So I was just solving the equation

Comment: @ShubhamJohri I got it. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$\sum_{k = 1}^{p-1}{p-1 \choose k-1} = 2^{p-1}$$ is not correct. It should be $$\sum_{k = 1}^{p}{p-1 \choose k-1} = 2^{p-1}$$.

$ \sum\limits_{k=1}^{p-1} \binom {p} {k}=\binom {p} {1}+\binom {p} {2}+...+\binom {p} {p-1}$ and $ \sum\limits_{k=0}^{p} \binom {p} {k}=\binom {p} {0}+\binom {p} {1}+...+\binom {p} {p}$. What differences do you find between these two sums? If you remember that $\binom {p} {0}=\binom {p} {p } (=1)$ then you can complete your argument.

Comment: How did you get that formula? Did you use index shift on the original summation formula

Comment: @GilbertS Yes, when you shift the index $0$ to $p-1$ becomes $1$ to $p$.

Comment: I got it. You get $\sum_{k=0}^{p}{p \choose k} = {p \choose 0} + 2^{p-1} + {p \choose p}$. Thanks alot

Comment: Actually its $\sum_{k=0}^p {p \choose k} = {p \choose 0} + 2^{p} - 2 + {p \choose p}$. I proved it. Thanks again